# Render Setup Bug when trying to delete RenderSetupLayer nodes through Node editor

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya, maya-api

My first post on StackOverflow!

I am currently trying to script a simple Render Setup tool to quickly allow the deletion of RenderSetup layers.

However, I've noticed that when I select the RenderSetupLayer nodes by name , it causes the "deleted" Render Layer inside the Render Setup GUI to partly grey out in the area where the "active layer" button sits. If I then close the window, it reports that there is a C++ error with the window,  giving the following error:

"maya error 510: Internal C++ object (RenderSetupWindow) already deleted."

Following this, I did a simple non-code-based test, where I simply opened up the Render Setup dialogue, created a new render layer, and deleted the RenderLayer and RenderSetupLayer nodes through the node editor window, and this resulted in the same "bug". Once I closed the window, I could not reopen, hinting at a very basic bug within Maya's RenderSetup interface. Very frustrating! Is this a known issue with Maya? Can anyone recommend a viable workflow to delete Layers from the RenderSetup system effectively?

Additionally, does anyone have any recommendations for selecting pre-existing collections from the Render Setup system? There are a lot of resources online, however I cannot find any details. I want to select the collection and assign to a variable, but I cannot do this on creation of the collection, only after.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 0):

Which Maya version was this? I have not had any issues with deleting renderlayers in maya 2018, anyway with python this could be a solution for you:

```
#modules
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderLayer as renderLayer
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup as renderSetup
rs = renderSetup.instance()

rs.clearAll() #for deleting all renderlayers

#to delete a specific renderlayer
rl_layer = rs.createRenderLayer("Layer") #create renderlayer
renderLayer.delete(rl_layer) #delete renderlayer
```